# Task 'assembleDebug' not found in project: 'xxx'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have a project which has some library. It is building fine when I run it directly, but when I try to build the project from the command line, with `gradlew android:assembleDebug --profile`, it gives following exception.

**Task 'assembleDebug' not found in project ':xxxx'**

Comment: put your gradle file here